# OCaml evaluation of expression, order?

Tags: expression, ocaml, evaluation

`add` is a function that is built in to OCaml.

Exp:

```
# add 5 1;;
- : int = 6
```

My question: what is the order of evaluation for `add 3 (add 5 3)`?

```
# add 3 (add 5 3);;
- : int = 11
```

Is `(add 5 3)` evaluated first to 8, then `add 3 (8)` is evaluated to 11? Or is `add 3` evaluated first into a function, and then `(add 5 3)` is used as a parameter for the function `(add 3)`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For what it's worth, there's no function named `add` that's built in to OCaml. (I.e., there's no such symbol in the Pervasives module.)

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.06.0

# add;;
Error: Unbound value add
```

The order of evaluation of a function and its arguments in OCaml is unspecified. So there is no guaranteed order.

This is documented in [Section 7.7.1 of the OCaml manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.06/expr.html#sec128).

If you want an evaluation to happen in a certain order, you can use `let` to evaluate each subexpression:

```
# let add a b = a + b;;
val add : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# let temp = add 5 3 in
  add 3 temp;;
- : int = 11
# let tempf = add 3 in
  tempf (add 5 3);;
- : int = 11
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to complete Jeffrey's answer, here is a version of `add` which lets you know when it is executed:

```
# let add a b =
    Printf.printf "Adding %d and %d...\n" a b;
    a + b;;

val add : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

Let's see it in action.

```
# add (add 1 2) (add 5 8);;

Adding 5 and 8...
Adding 1 and 2...
Adding 3 and 13...

- : int = 16
```

So here, the second `add` is evaluated first, but you can't really count on it since it is not specified.

Here is the same example using a local `let` to force the order:

```
# let x = add 1 2 in
  add x (add 5 8);;

Adding 1 and 2...
Adding 5 and 8...
Adding 3 and 13...

- : int = 16
```

And now using partial application.

```
# let add_3 = add 3 in
  add_3 (add 5 8);;

Adding 5 and 8...
Adding 3 and 13...

- : int = 16
```

---

Of course, with (pure) functional programming, order of execution does not matter since everything is immutable. But OCaml is't purely functional, so these little tricks are good to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

The order of evaluation of arguments in OCaml is unspecified, meaning it can change from one compiler to another.

Let's create a function that's evaluated in two stages:

```
let mul a =
  Printf.printf "got a: %i\n%!" a;
  fun b ->
    Printf.printf "got b: %i\n%!" b;
    a * b
```

Running this with `utop` (or `ocaml`) shows right-to-left evaluation:

```
# mul (mul 2 3) (mul 5 7);;
got a: 5
got b: 7
got a: 2
got b: 3
got a: 6
got b: 35
- : int = 210
```

A `let`-`in` can be introduced to force evaluation order, resulting in a different sequence of printfs:

```
# let mul6 = mul (mul 2 3) in mul6 (mul 5 7);;
got a: 2
got b: 3
got a: 6
got a: 5
got b: 7
got b: 35
- : int = 210
```

Comment: Note that in the current compiler this happens to work like feeding a stack machine. All arguments are evaluated in reverse order an put on stack. Then the function is taken and applied to the arguments as they get pulled back from the stack again.